# How to use AWS SDK for iOS with Objective-C instead of Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm connecting my Objective-C based app to AWS S3 filestore by doing this by following [this AWS-amplify tutorial](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn) . It's using the AWS Amplify CLI and the AWS SDK for iOS (AWSAppSync). My problem is that a Swift snippet needs to be added to the appDelegate file. However, my appDelegate is Objective-C and I don't know what's the best way to add it correctly.

[1] Is this extra code snippet in the delegate file really necessary? I'm only going to upload images to the S3 filestore.

[2] If necessary, what's the best workaround? (making a separate swift file and bridging it to the appDelegate file feels a bit too hacky)

Here's the snippet:

```
import AWSAppSync

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        do {
            // You can choose the directory in which AppSync stores its persistent cache databases
            let cacheConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()

            // AppSync configuration & client initialization
            let appSyncServiceConfig = try AWSAppSyncServiceConfig()
            let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: appSyncServiceConfig,
                                                                  cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration)
            appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
        }
        // other methods
        return true
    }
```

So far I've tried using this piece of code:

```
#import <AWSAppSync/AWSAppSync.h>
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
}
```

But I get the errors:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'DefaultServiceRegionType'
Use of undeclared identifier 'credentialsProvider'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AWSCore`

Import the AWSCore header in the objective c app delegate.

```
@import AWSCore;
```

And Create a service configuration in the

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

application delegate method.

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoRegionType
                                                                                                identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Import the appropriate headers for the services(May be inside your view controller) you are using. The header file import convention is @import AWSServiceName; as

```
@import AWSS3;
@import AWSDynamoDB;
@import AWSSQS;
@import AWSSNS;
@import AWSCognito;
```

And implement a call to the AWS services.

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = yourBucket;
uploadRequest.key = yourKey;
uploadRequest.body = yourDataURL;
uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    // Do something with the response
    return nil;
}];
```